Determine if point can be projected on any segment in polyline
I am trying to implement a script that determines if a series of points can be projected on any segment of a polyline. The projection must be exactly on the segment, not in the rest of the line determined by it. At this step, I am not interested in the coordinates of the point where the projection falls, just if it is possible for the point to meet the requirements.
I already know that a solution would be to find the projection of each point on each line defined by the segments and compare the coordinates to determine if it falls onto the segment or not. I am more interested in if there is a solution that would be more efficient than this. or any alternate solution in general.
